# How to send the output values of a Lookup activity in an email in Data Factory?

Tags: azure, lookup, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to send a LookUp activity output values as part of a body parameter in a POST request using LogicApp, which uses three parameters: "to", "email_body", "subject".

The LookUp activity depends on a query, and it may return from 2 rows up to 10 rows.
According to Azure, the output of the activity should look like this:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "column1":value1,
            "column2":value2,
            "column3":value3
        },
        {
            "column1":value4,
            "column2":value5,
            "column3":value6
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, the query returned 2 rows, but how can I attach every output value to the POST body without having to use  `@activity('lookup_act').output.value[0].column1` and so on for every value?

The POST body is the following:

```
{
    "email_body": "Hi, the following tables have been updated:
        @{activity('lookup_act').output.value[0].column1}
        @{activity('lookup_act').output.value[1].column1}",
    "subject": "Update on tables",
    "to": "email@domain.com"
}
```

I've tried using `@activity('lookup_act').output.value` to bring every value but it won't work.

Is there a way to call every single output value? If so, how can it be done and paste into a table?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: try this `@string(activity('lookup_act').output.value)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get all values in mail:

**1. Get whole lookup output array in mail.**

- First get the results from Lookup activity and then pass the output of this activity by **converting it into a string** otherwise you will get error regarding deserialization.

[image]

```json
{"message":"@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value)",
"dataFactoryName":"@{pipeline().DataFactory}",
"pipelineName":"@{pipeline().Pipeline}",
"receiver":"@{pipeline().parameters.receiver}"}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**2. Get all the respective values column wise.**

- First get the results from Lookup activity then take a foreach loop and create append variable for every column to store every column value in single array.

ForEach activity setting:
[image]

Took append variable activity and created `Idarray` variable. and gave `item().id` as value to store all id values in a single array.
[image]

Then in web activity passed below body for getting all arrays.
[image]

```json
{"message":"@{string(variables('Idarray'))} as Id, @{string(variables('Namearray'))} as Name, @{string(variables('ProfessionArray'))} as Profession",
"dataFactoryName":"@{pipeline().DataFactory}",
"pipelineName":"@{pipeline().Pipeline}",
"receiver":"@{pipeline().parameters.receiver}"}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]